# How to pass $course in to sectiontext_survey_display()?

Tags: php, oop, content-management-system, moodle

Is there any option in **moodle** to pass `$course` in to another function which is

`function sectiontext_survey_display($data) {}`

in to

`function sectiontext_survey_display($data, $course) {}`

Actually I just wanna filter some items on the basis of course ID and Category

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Questionnaire is an activity plugin rather than part of the core Moodle

https://moodle.org/plugins/view.php?plugin=mod_questionnaire

I'm guessing you could try something like this to get the course id

```
$coursed id = $this->course->id;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am in `questiontypes.class.php` does your code work in the page ?

Comment: Not sure, haven't used the plugin, just had a look at the code. It looks like the parent class holds a course object, so you should be able to access it somehow. Can you step through the code using a debugger then inspect the properties? Or just do a var_dump($this) in the function.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found solution :)

```
global $course;
var_dump($course)
```

Comment: That's the current course - it *might* not be same the course in the questionnaire though so use with caution.

Comment: @Russell England really ? I am using `if()` is that ok ?

Comment: global $COURSE; is the current course being viewed - that's correct. (Although it can also be the $SITE when no course is being viewed) But any plugin can be pass the course as a parameter too - so the questionnaire plugin might might be looking at a different course to the one being looked at - I wouldn't depend on the global $course object - try to use the course property in the parent questionnaire class.

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough, sectiontext_survey_display appears to be an unused, private function within the questionnaire addon (at least within the version that I have looked at) - I'm not sure that extending it will be very helpful.

Unfortunately, the class in question links to a survey, which can be used in multiple instances of the questionnaire module, which means that the same survey could be used in multiple courses. There is no way you can get directly from the questionnaire_question class back to a course.

The best you can manage (and, in reality this will probably always work), is to use either:

```
global $COURSE;
```

or

```
global $PAGE;
$PAGE->course;
```

Both of these should work (although the second is encouraged in more recent versions of Moodle).